# Collect Tomcat statistics locally and not remotely

Tags: java, tomcat, jmx

Is there any way **other than** RMI to collect Tomcat statistics? I want to monitor tomcat locally and not remotely. Is there any way? Or should I write a custom MBean to achieve this?

I know about this:
JMXServiceURL url = new JMXServiceURL("service:jmx:rmi:///jndi/rmi://localhost:8081/jmxrmi");
JMXConnector jmxc = JMXConnectorFactory.connect(url);

But I don't want to use RMI to monitor tomcat.

Comment: What's your objection to using the interface that is provided for the purpose?

Answer (score 1):

No, you don't need RMI. Just do:

```
MBeanServer managedBeanServer = ManagementFactory.getPlatformMBeanServer();
```